# Native base header adding extra height in iPhone x

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using the native base for the screen layout in react native. The Header component in the native base is adding an extra height apart from the actual height that I have specified.

My current native base version is 2.13.12.
I'm facing the issue in the iPhone only and for the iPhone x and above models.
Someone please helps me with fixing the issue.
[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u2jr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `forceInset={{ top: 'never' }}` at the main root file to remove the extra padding. for example:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: 'never' }}>
 <App />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: <Container>
  <Header style={{backgroundColor:"#FFF",height:80,alignItems:"center",borderBottomWidth:1.5,borderBottomColor: '#48C3C5'}} >
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="#48C3C5"/>
    <Left style={{flex:0.2,justifyContent:"flex-end"}} >
    </Left>
    <Body style={{flex:0.6,alignItems:"center"}}>
       <Title style={{color:"#000",fontFamily:"Avenir-Black"}}>Messages</Title>
    </Body>
    <Right style={{flex:0.2}}>
    </Right>
  </Header>
</Container>

Comment: I have given the component like this

Comment: Is that the issue with the version of native base I'm using?

Comment: I solved the issue by adding a paddingTop:0 style for the <Header>